# How to run RestComm Sip Servlet Container on Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, sip, tomcat8, restcomm, sip-servlet

I'm trying to run RestComm Sip Servlet on Tomcat 8. I'm a Java programming and have been using Tomcat for quite a while, but I'm a totally newbie in Sip Servlet programming.

I've read the Restcomm SIP Servlets User Guide in http://documentation.telestax.com/core/sip_servlets/SIP_Servlets_Server_User_Guide.html, but the Tomcat Installation guide is somehow outdated. Since is still referring to the Restcomm SIP Servlets for Tomcat 7 bundled. The download link for that bundled now point to download page for Restcomm SIP Servlet container source code.

I've used maven to build the sip-servlets-4.0.125 source I downloaded from the link. For Tomcat 8, I notice that sip-servlets-tomcat-8-4.0.125.jar is created.

What should I do in order to make the RestComm Sip Servlet 4.0.125 container on Tomcat 8 ? And which version of Tomcat 8 should I use ? 8.0.X or 8.5.X ?

Kind regards,
Ahmad R. Djarkasih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pick the Tomcat 8 bundle from https://github.com/RestComm/sip-servlets/releases/tag/3.2.0-89. There is nothing else to do than to run it.